# A subgroup $H$ of $G$ has the property $P$ if $H\neq G$ and $\forall x,y \in G\setminus H\implies xy\in H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $(G,\cdot)$ be a group with $n$ elements (for a) and b) $n\ge4$ and for c) we only know that $n\in \mathbb{N}$). We say that a subgroup $H$ of $G$ has the property $P$ if $H\neq G$ and $\forall x,y \in G\setminus H\implies xy\in H$.
>   a) Give an example of a group $G$ which has three distinct subgroups $H, K, L$ with the property $P$ such that $G= H \cup K \cup L$.
>   b)If $H, K, L$ are distinct subgroups of $G$ which have the property $P$ and $G= H \cup K \cup L$, find $|H\cap K \cap L|$.
>   c)If $G$ has the distinct subgroups $H_1$ and $H_2$ which have the propety $P$ and $H_1 \cap H_2=\{e\}$, prove that $G$ is isomorphic to $K_4$(the Klein four group).
>   d)Prove that for $n\ge 2$, $(\mathbb{Z_n},+)$ has at most one subgroup with the property $P$.

For a), both $K_4$ and $Q_8$ work.
For b), I think that we should use the principle of exclusion and inclusion, but I couldn't make much progress ( I am having a hard time finding the intersections of the subgroups, but maybe there is some other easier way).
c) seems reminescent of a), all I have tried was to consider the set $H_1 H_2$, whose cardinality is $\operatorname{ord}H_1 \cdot \operatorname{ord}H_2$, but it didn't prove to be useful at all.
For d), I considered the fact that $\mathbb{Z_n}$ has exactly one subgroup of order $k$ (which is the cyclic subgroup generated by $\frac{n}{k}$), but I didn't get any further.
EDIT: I will present the proof I found in a book for b) (I hadn't found it when I posted this, I initially found this problem somewhere else) :
Since $H$ has the property $P$ and $G\setminus H=\{x_1, x_2, ..., x_t\}$, then we have the distinct elements $x_1^2, x_1 x_2,..., x_1 x_t \in H$, so $|G\setminus H|\le |H|$. Hence, $|H|\ge \frac{n}{2}$ and since $H\neq G$, from Lagrange's theorem it follows that $n$ is even and $|H|=\frac{n}{2}$.
If $H$ and $K$ have the property $P$, then $|H|=|K|=\frac{n}{2}$. Since $H\neq K$ and they have the same number of elements it follows that $|H\setminus K|=|K\setminus H|$.
We get that $\forall x,y \in H\setminus K \implies xy\in H \cap K$, so $|H \setminus K| \le |H \cap K|$. Thus, $|H\cap K| \ge \frac{|H|}{2}=\frac{n}{4}$. But $H\cap K$ is a subgroup of $H$, $H\cap K \neq H$ and from Lagrange's theorem we deduce that $|H\cap K|=\frac{n}{4}$, so $n=4m$, $m\in N$.
If the subgroups $H, K, L$ have the property $P$, then $|H|=|K|=|L|=2m$ and $|H\cap K|=|K\cap L|=|H \cap L|=m$, so $|H\cap K \cap L|=|G|-|H|-|K|-|L|+|H \cap K|+ |K \cap L| + |H\cap L|=m$.

Comment: I don't think you can say anything about $|H\cap K\cap L|$ in the abstract; but you should be able to say something about its *index* in $G$. Is that perhaps what you were meant to find?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can say anything about $|H\cap K\cap L|$ in the abstract.

Let $K_4=C_2\times C_2$ be the Klein $4$-group, and let $B=\langle (x,e)\rangle$, $C=\langle (e,x)\rangle$, and $D=\langle (x,x)\rangle$ be the three proper nontrivial subgroups of $K_4$ whose union is $K_4$. Note that each of $B$, $C$, and $D$ have property $P$.

Let $A$ be an arbitrary group, and let $G=A\times K_4$. Now let $H=A\times B$, $K=A\times C$, and $L=A\times D$.

Note that $H,K,L$ are pairwise distinct. That $G=H\cup K\cup L$. And that each of $H$, $K$, and $L$ have property $P$: if $(w_1,z_1), (w_2,z_2)\in G$, $(w_i,z_i)\notin H$, then we must have $z_1,z_2\notin B$. But then $z_1z_2\in B$, since $B$ has property $P$, so $(w_1,z_1)(w_2,z_2)\in H$. Similar arguments work for $K$ and $L$.

But $H\cap K\cap L = A\times\{1\}$, so $|H\cap K\cap L| = |A|$. Since $A$ was an arbitrary group, you get that the intersection can have arbitrary cardinality.

However, you *can* say that the index of $H\cap K\cap L$ in $G$ must be $4$.

Indeed, first note that that an element of $G$ is always in at least one of $H$, $K$, and $L$. I claim that if it is in more than one of them, then it is in all of them. Indeed, suppose that $x\in H\cap K$. Since $G$ is not the union of two subgroups, there exists $g\in G$ such that $g\notin H\cup K$. Then $g\in L$; now, $xg\notin H$, $xg\notin K$, but $xg\in G$, so $xg\in L$. Since $g\in L$, then $x\in L$, which is what we wanted to show. Symmetric arguments hold if you start with an element in $H\cap L$ or in $K\cap L$. Note that we did not use property $P$ here.

Now, $H\cap K\cap L\triangleleft G$: if $x\in H\cap K\cap L$, and $y\in G$, say $y\in H$. If $y\in K$ or $y\in L$, then $y\in H\cap K\cap L$ so $yxy^{-1}\in H\cap K\cap L$. Thus, we may assume that $y\in H$ and $y\notin L\cup K$. Then $yx\notin L$, and $y^{-1}\notin L$, so by property $P$ we have $yxy^{-1}\in L$. Similarly, $yx\notin K$, $y^{-1}\notin K$, so by property $P$ we have $yxy^{-1}\in K$. And clearly $yxy^{-1}\in H$. Thus, $yxy^{-1}\in H\cap K\cap L$, so $(H\cap K\cap L)\triangleleft G$. Thus, we may mod out by $H\cap K\cap L$. Now apply (c) to the resulting quotient, since $H\cap K=H\cap K\cap L$.

Comment: Thanks ! In the meantime I found b) in a book where it has a solution. I copied that solution in my post. There are a couple of steps in it which I do not understand, but your solution looks all right to me, so I guess theirs may be flawed.

Comment: @user69503: They are proving that $|H\cap K\cap L| = \frac{1}{4}|G|$, which is the same as saying it has index $4$ in $G$, so it's the same answer. My point is that you aren't giving an absolute value for $|H\cap K\cap L|$, but rather just a relative value, which the phrasing of the question does not make clear is sufficient.

Comment: I understand, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

c) First, observe that if $g$ is in neither $H_1$ nor $H_2$, then $g^2$ lies in $H_1 \cap H_2$. Therefore $g^2 = e$. Now suppose $k$ also lies in neither $H_1$ nor $H_2$. Then $kg \in H_1 \cap H_2 = \{e\} \Rightarrow kg^2 = k = g.$ Therefore if there is an element outside $H_1$ and $H_2$, it is unique.

Let $a \in H_1$, $b \in H_2$, where $a, b$ non-identity. Then $ab$ is  in neither $H_1$ nor $H_2$. So $g$ exists, assuming $H_1$ and $H_2$ are both non-trivial.

This paragraph shows that $H_1,H_2$ are non-trivial. First see that $|G| > 2$, since if $|G| = 1$, then $H_1$ is not proper, and if $|G| = 2,$ the only non-proper subgroup is trivial, so the union $H_1$ and $H_2$ is not $G$. Suppose wlog $H_1$ is trivial. Then pick distict $g_1, g_2$ not in $H_1$. Then $g_1^2$ and $g_1g_2$ both lie in $H_1$. Therefore $g_1^2 = g_1g_2$, so $g_1 = g_2$, contradiction.

ok. So we've shown that $|G| = |H_1|+|H_2|$. But by Lagrange, we have $|H_1|$ divides $|H_2|$ and simultaneously $|H_2|$ divides $|H_1|$. So $|H_1| = |H_2|,$ and $H_1,H_2$ are both index 2 subgroups of $G$. Hence, they are normal. Since they intersect trivially and are normal, they commute elementwise (consider commutator). So the subgroup
$H_1H_2 = \{h_1h_2 : h_1 \in H_1, h_2 \in H+2\}$ is a valid group and is isomorphic to $H_1 \times H_2$ by the direct product theorem. Let $t = |H_1| = |H_2|.$ Then $|H_1 \times H_2| = t^2$ divides $|G| = 2t$. Therefore $t$ is 1 or 2. We've shown $t$ is not 1. Therefore $t=2$. Therefore $G$ has order 4. $G$ cannot be isomorphic to $C_4$, since there is only one non-trivial proper subgroup of $C_4$. Therefore $G$ is $C_2 \times C_2$. You've already shown this group works.

d). Every subgroup of $Z_n$ is cyclic. Let $H$ be your subgroup with property $P$. Then $H$ is generated by the smallest positive integer $x$ such that $x \in H$. $1 \notin H$ as $H$ is proper. Therefore $1+1 = 2 \in H$. Therefore $H$ is the group generated by $2$.